# Avoid nginx escaping query parameters on proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I to proxy `/api` on a domain, I have this location block.

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    rewrite_log on;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1$is_args$args break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
}
```

It works fine as long as the URLs do not have query parameters, but as soon as they do, I get errors on the upstream server like these `Could not find path: /records%3fname=hoegh.io`

The `%3f` in question here is an URL encoded `?`, and since it's URL encoded, the upstream server does not recognize it. That might be retarded, but I was hoping it was possible to get nginx to handle this correctly (ie. not escape the URL before passing it to the proxy).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did the solution provided work for you? Please accept the answer

Comment: "retarded" is an unfortunate and derogatory choice of word here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.  $args is passed along automatically.

If you wish to modify the $args that are passed you have to override.

```
set $args "foo=bar";
```

for instance.

Working solution should go as follows:

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    rewrite_log on;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this instead? It's generally not needed to add the query string as Nginx adds it automatically:

```
rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1? break;
```

Comment: I did have that earlier, but then it seemed the query string wasn't passed along at all.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to type the `?` at the end of the redirect string