# Avoid nginx decoding query parameters on proxy_pass (equivalent to AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode)

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I use nginx as a load balencer in front of several tomcats. In my incoming requests, I have encoded query parameters. But when the request arrives to tomcat, parameters are decoded :

incoming request to nginx:

```
curl -i "http://server/1.1/json/T;cID=1234;pID=1200;rF=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F"
```

incoming request to tomcat:

```
curl -i "http://server/1.1/json/T;cID=1234;pID=1200;rF=http:/www.google.com/"
```

I don't want my request parameters to be transformed, because in that case my tomcat throws a 405 error.

My nginx configuration is the following :

```
upstream tracking  {
    server front-01.server.com:8080;
    server front-02.server.com:8080;
    server front-03.server.com:8080;
    server front-04.server.com:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name tracking.server.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/tracking-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/tracking-error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://tracking/webapp;
    }
}
```

In my current apache load balancer configuration, I have the [AllowEncodedSlashes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) directive that preserves my encoded parameters:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

I need to move from apache to nginx.

My question is quite the opposite from this question : [Avoid nginx escaping query parameters on proxy_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207505/avoid-nginx-escaping-query-parameters-on-proxy-pass)

Comment: Shouldn't your query string start by a question mark ? i.e. `?cID=1234;pID=1200;rF=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481664/semicolon-as-url-query-separator)

Comment: yes, and no Vianney. This is a "feature" of the framework RestEasy... But this will change in the future, believe me :) I think we should use a POST request instead

Comment: W3c : 

    We recommend that HTTP server implementors, and in particular, CGI implementors support the use of ";" in place of "&" to save authors the trouble of escaping "&" characters in this manner.

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481664/semicolon-as-url-query-separator?lq=1

Comment: Yes, I read the same. Also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme. Besides, making the query string starting by a question mark (followed by semicolons) or directly by a semicolon seems to have a slightly different meaning. According to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt, semicolons are "often used" within path's segments, e.g. http://acme.com/foo;v=1/bar;v=2.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I finally found the solution: I need to pass [`$request_uri` parameter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) :

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://tracking/webapp$request_uri;
}
```

That way, characters that were encoded in the original request will *not* be decoded, i.e. will be passed as-is to the proxied server.

Comment: Wow, this indeed works and should be the default. I don't see why nginx would need to interfere with the encoding.

Comment: This does not work if your location is anything other than root.

Comment: If you have done a URL rewrite before passing proxy, you should use `$uri` instead.
You can read more on the difference between `$request_uri` and `$uri`

Comment: It's frikkin crazy that NGINX is decoding URL parameters and then passing them invalidly into URLs. The same happens when you match `(.*)` in a path and then pass it to a URL rewrite (or proxy_pass) as in `/$1/`. If there are spaces encoded as `%20` in your original URL, NGINX will pass them on as ` ` which is invalid in a URL.

Answer (score 18):

[Jean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20514632/1338062) is good, but it does not work with sublocations. In that case, the more generic answer is:

```
location /path/ {
  if ($request_uri ~* "/path/(.*)") {
    proxy_pass http://tracking/webapp/$1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone provide a link to any documentation containing this info?

Comment: @Lrnk This answer is using this. -> http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if to do a PCRE regex. The $1 is the first capture group. You'll see this is a kind of crummy way of telling nginx to drop the first part of the /path/. To be clear this if() will ALWAYS be successful because the if has essentially been validated by the location directive already.

Comment: After a million iterations on this stupid problem this answer was the only one that worked for me when I needed to drop the incoming non-root path.

Comment: This will work until you have spaces in your path. NGINX witll decode `/foo%20bar/` and send your user to an invalid URL `/webapp/foo bar/`.

Answer (score 17):

Note that URL decoding, commonly known as *[`$uri`](http://nginx.org/r/$uri) "normalisation"* within the documentation of nginx, happens before the backend IFF:

- either any URI is specified within `proxy_pass` itself, even if just the trailing slash all by itself,
- or, URI is changed during the processing, e.g., through `rewrite`.

---

Both conditions are explicitly documented at http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass (emphasis mine):

- > If the `proxy_pass` directive is specified ***with a URI***, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a ***normalized*** request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive
- > If `proxy_pass` is specified ***without a URI***, the request URI is passed to the server in the ***same form as sent by a client*** when the original request is processed, ***or*** the full ***normalized*** request URI is passed ***when*** processing the ***changed URI***

---

The solution depends on whether or not you need to change the URL between the front-end and the backend.

- If no URI change is required:

  ```
  # map `/foo` to `/foo`:
  location /foo {
      proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;  # no URI -- not even just a slash
  }
  ```
- Otherwise, if you do need to swap or map `/api` of the front-end with `/app` on the backend, then you can get the original URI from the [`$request_uri`](http://nginx.org/r/$request_uri) variable, and the use the `rewrite` directives over the `$uri` variable similar to a DFA (BTW, if you want more `rewrite` DFA action, take a look at [mdoc.su](http://mdoc.su/)).  Note that the `return 400` part is needed in case someone tries to get around your second rewrite rule, as it wouldn't match something like `//api/`.

  ```
  # map `/api` to `/app`:
  location /foo {
      rewrite  ^  $request_uri;            # get original URI
      rewrite  ^/api(/.*)  /app$1  break;  # drop /api, put /app
      return 400;   # if the second rewrite won't match
      proxy_pass    http://localhost:8080$uri;
  }
  ```
- If you simply want to add a prefix for the backend, then you can just use the `$request_uri` variable right away:

  ```
  # add `/webapp` to the backend:
  location / {
      proxy_pass    http://localhost:8080/webapp$request_uri;
  }
  ```

You might also want to take a look at [a related answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/37584637/1122270), which shows some test-runs of the code similar to the above.

Comment: Out of all the answers to this I believe this is the best one. I'm not an nginx expert but I believe that the answer given by @user1338062 will cause nginx to parse the uri string twice. Once to hit the location block, and once for the if() statement that trivally returns true. I would think nginx would be smart enough to combine the rewrite rules into the location rules, so this rewrite approach would be better, but I don't know.

Comment: In your middle example 

    rewrite  ^/api(/.*)  /app$1  break;  # drop /api, put /app
    return 400;   # if the second rewrite won't match
    proxy_pass    http://localhost:8080$uri;

The capture group includes a / but so does the production rule of /$1 which I think results in the output proxy_pass url having double slashes.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. The capture group seemed to stop at the ? in a query with query params, and wouldn't pass them on to the upstream server.

Comment: @Jazzepi For double-slash, I don't see any mentions of `/$1` in my answer, so, I think you have your own code doing the double-slash; note that this whole code was fully tested as per my related answer (see link in this very answer), and there's no double-slash there! Thanks for the upvote!  For query params, I'm pretty sure everything is still supposed to be preserved as-is; I just tested `echo localhost:4300/{api,dec,mec,nod}/save/http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com\?test\&test | xargs -n1 curl` against the conf from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37584637/1122270, and don't see any issues nor duplicates.

Comment: how the second rewrite could ever match as the `location` block is for `/foo` ?

Comment: This example will not work for URLs with spaces. As I mentioned above NGINX will decode `/foo%20bar/` to `/foo bar/` so you cannot use `$1` in all cases as it will be invalid (URLs cannot have spaces).

Answer (score 13):

There is one documented option for [Nginx proxy_pass](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) directive

> If it is necessary to transmit URI in the unprocessed form then directive proxy_pass should be used **without URI part**:

```rb
location  /some/path/ {
  proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
}
```

so in your case it could be like this. Do not worry about request URI it will be passed over to upstream servers

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://tracking;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but I really need to add a URI because several webapps are on the same server.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. The latest jenkins (1.554.1) was complaining that my proxy configuration was wrong due to mishandling of encoded slashes. I changed by nginx configuration to  "location /jenkins {  proxy_pass [http://localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080);  ..}"  and the jenkins errors went away.

Comment: FYI I had this issue because I had a `/` at the end of my backend: like `proxy_pass http://my-backend/`. Removing the final `/` solved the problem (after 4 hours of trial&error).

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the problem is not on the nginx side - you must set the uri encoding on Tomcat connector to UTF-8.